# problem with react native npx initialisation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, npx

i've got this problem, i've installed almost everything what i could, android studio, jdk and things which were required for running android simulator

but when i'm trying to run:
npx react-native@latest init MyAwesomeProject

it always shows:
✔ Downloading template
⠋ Copying template/home/bedena/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:265
if (!chownErOk(er)) throw er
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/bedena/Desktop/programming/nativereactbootcamp/MyAwesomeProjectInit/android/gradle.properties'
at Object.chmodSync (node:fs:1991:3)
at Object.chmodSync (/home/bedena/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:263:21)
at ReadStream. (/home/bedena/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/copyFiles.js:83:19)
at ReadStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:132:10)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'chmod',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: '/home/bedena/Desktop/programming/nativereactbootcamp/MyAwesomeProjectInit/android/gradle.properties'
}

it creates project folder, but files inside it are empty and scripts doesn't work

who knows what's happening?

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved the issue by downgrading my Node version from 18.x to 16.x. I think latest React Native version (0.72) has some issues with Node versions 18.x or higher. My current config is: Node: 16.20.2, NPM: 8.19.4, Yarn: not installed, Ubuntu: 22.04.3

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to your node version. As of today the same error happens with node v20, but after downgrading to v18 the issue is no longer there.